# Is there a way to restrict access and visibility to end points when using google cloud endpoints?

Tags: java, swagger, google-cloud-endpoints

We generate our swagger/openAPI documents based on annotations in our java code.  There are end points in the code that are there just for our internal usage.  These are endpoints that we don't want accessible or even visible publicly.

It's possible, I guess that we could post process the swagger file and remove these endpoints, but that adds another step in the build process. What would really be nice is if could just tag them in such a way that the google cloud endpoint load-balancer saw the tag it  would ignore the endpoint. Is such a thing possible?

I imagine we could do something like this by identifying them as requiring access, and then not configure anyone to have access, but I wondered if there was another path that might yield the same or better results.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you can only manage who can access your endpoint with

1. API keys
2. Firebase authentication
3. Auth0
4. Service accounts

but this is only to [authenticate](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method), however what you want to accomplish is not possible at the moment, I could suggest you [create a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187193&template=0). So the GCP team knows you are interested on the functionality and maybe implemented on the future.